# How to debug the Networkmanager-dispatcher-variables

Tags: environment-variables, networkmanager

I want to debug a script that contains Networkmanager-dispacher-variables like DEVICE_IFACE, IP4_GATEWAY. The [Networkmanager-manual](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.html) describes these variables but doesn't mention how to debug them.

I searched a lot but i am unable to figure out how to get the value of these variables. When i echo on the command line like echo ${DEVICE_IFACE} i get no value.

Answer (score 0):

In the `NetworkManager` manual page you're reffering to, is stated :

> The environment contains more information about the interface and the
>   connection. The following variables are available for the use in the
>   dispatcher scripts:
>   [...]
>   DEVICE_IFACE

So this environment is obviously set up by dispatcher.d, and only accessible to scripts launched from there.

For example, you could put this line in a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` :

`echo "interface $DEVICE_IFACE" > /tmp/myscript.log`

Still referring to the manual page of `NetworkManager`, you will need to make it owned by root, executable, and not writable by group or others, for instance :

`# chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/myscript`

`# chmod a+x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/myscript`

`# chmod go-w /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/myscript`

Then, restarting NetworkManager, you should read something like "interface wlan0" in `/tmp/myscript.log`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the dispatcher scripts is logged by systemd; you can view it with `sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager-dispatcher`. So just echo the variables and then look at the log.

A similar answer to a similar question can be found at https://serverfault.com/a/1056299/310447